# Retrieving information from another page

Tags: php

I am thinking of a way to send a request to page, and receive a request from a page and then read it. The problem is that I dont know what is the most efficient way of achieving so.

```
  $result=file_get_contents('scan_results.php');

      $scanning=true;

      while($scanning){
             if(stristr($result,'Nothing to scan.')){
                    $scanning=false;
                }
      }
```

Right now, I simply send a request to the page and try to scrape the page for the sentence 'Nothing to scan.'.

The page scan_results.php, should do a few tasks, so I loop it until I get 'Nothing to scan'.. So basically, I am thinking of using a better way to check when I get the sentence nothing to scan..

Comment: try this : `  $result=file_get_contents('http://'.'domain.com/scan_results.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Try cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd try to benchmark `cURL` and `file_get_contents()` to see the difference. +1 because cURL is a better way.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the scrapping option..perhaps I could do it with a session..so whenever the tasks on the other page are finished..I could set the session variable to finished for example..But when I tried to do it,,it didnt wrong..or may be I did it badly